# Sorting all fields in a struct array based on one field in matlab

Tags: matlab, struct

Imagine that columns f1 and f2 are one struct called inputStruct and columns f3 and f4 are another struct called outputStruct (sorry for bad formatting). I want to sort all fields in inputStruct  in terms of ascending order of inputStruct.f2, so that the output would be outputStruct (columns f3 and f4). How would I approach this?

f1_f2 |f3_f4

a__4    ***|*** c__1

b__2    **|**   b__2

c__1    **|**   e__3

d__5    **|**   a__4

e__3    **|**   d__5

Comment: What exactly will be the output? Edit your question to include the output. Please fix the formatting. Writing it in MATLAB's syntax will be better. Note that fields cannot start with numbers, so `inputStruct.2` is invalid

Comment: I added edits. I understand fields cannot be numbers, this is a concept question for a code I am developing.

Comment: So why make incorrect statement when you understand that?

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: "I want to sort all fields" -- you cannot sort the fields of a struct, they have no order. It's a dictionary. You can sort the elements of a struct array, or you can sort the rows of a matrix, etc. -- Also, please use the formatting commands that you have available in the edit box. The "{}" button will format selected text as code. It's hard to understand, does `a__4` represent a field name, or are you using the `_` key as spacing? If so, use proper formatting for spacing, it'll help us understand you.

Comment: It seems that the answer below doesn't help you. You need to help us help you. This question is **very** unclear. You need to add a few lines of MATLAB code that create an example struct that matches the struct you're working with. Please read here >[mcve]<.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sort` to get the `outputStruct.f4` and corresponding indices. Use these indices to rearrange `inputStruct.f1` and get `outputStruct.f3`.

```
[outputStruct.f4, ind] = sort(inputStruct.f2);
outputStruct.f3 = inputStruct.f1(ind);
```

or for multiple fields, just loop through all the fields:

```
[~, ind] = sort(inputStruct.f2);   %Sorting according to field f2
fns = fieldnames(inputStruct);     %Retrieving the names of all the fields

for k = 1:numel(fns)               %Looping for each field
    outputStruct.(fns{k}) = inputStruct.(fns{k})(ind);
end
%Note: This creates outputStruct with the same fields as that of inputStruct
%but that can be adjusted if needed
```